# How to update an entry in strapi using flutter

Tags: flutter, strapi

When i try to update an entry on my strapi database using put method, i give back the error 405, i checked the error and it means that i have no authorization, but i have check all box on Public and still not possible to change the value

here the code i have wrote for testing the update

```
Future getData() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("http://localhost:1337/api/prove"),
    );

    setState(() {
      prova = Prova.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    });
  }

  Future updateData() async {
    if (controller.text.isEmpty) {
      print("no input");
      return;
    }
    final response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse("http://localhost:1337/api/prove"),
      headers: {
        "Authorization":
            "bearer ${dotenv.env["token"]}"
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        {
          "data": {
            "titolo": controller.text,
          }
        },
      ),
    );
    print(response.body);
    print(response.statusCode);
    getData();
  }
```

For resolving the error i have tried to use the api token, and the jwt token, and i still get the 405 error

Comment: Did you debug it and check what `"bearer ${dotenv.env["token"]}"` actually *is* when you run your code? If not, that should be your first step. If it is what you *expect* it to be, you need to debug the server, there is nothing you can do on the client side about it.

Comment: 405 means method not allowed, so you have an error in url you are trying to put

Comment: In the end I figured out what was the problem, i was requesting to the wrong endpoint, thanks for the helping